# Is this enough stud to attach drywall to?

Tags: drywall, framing, screws, fastening

I'm working on some framing. On an interior corner, because of where the divider wall ended up being, I've got only 5/8" of stud showing beyond where the perpendicular wall comes out.

Is that enough stud to reasonably believe I'll be able to securely get some screws in to hold up the edge of the drywall or do I need to throw a whole new 2x4 in next to it, giving me more than 2" of wood to safely get the screws into?

I've got the lumber, but I don't want to put a 10' board in there if I don't have to.

Comment: Any insulation behind the drywall that might try to push the drywall out?  If not, I would just be careful driving the screws in.

Comment: Good point, @crip659, this is an exterior wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not sweat it. When drywall is run on long walls, it is stopped in the center of the studs, never perfectly, and that is only a mounting surface of 3/4", when you have 2 sheets meeting on one stud. You are only 1/8" off from that.
Of course, it is not a big deal to add an extra stud to make it easier, then again, is the extra work of adding a stud, making it that much easier? Just mincing words here....

Answer (score 3):

If it were me I would put the 2x4 in there. Otherwise your screwing into the very edge of the sheet rock. One 2x4 won't break the bank. If you have 2x4 scraps you could use them as well. It's not structural support.

Comment: 2x4 scraps are the answer.

Comment: The drawback is that this is an exterior wall and another 2x4 there limits the insulation in that cavity. I realize I hadn't mentioned that in the question...

Comment: @FreeMan I had to do a little research, a stud will conduct some thermal energy. Not sure I would worry about one extra stud. If you are you could rip some 2x4 scraps. You will get maximum insulation and have a solid surface for your sheet rock. Are the walls 2x6 or 2x4?